# Can I report Q promise progress without creating a deferred?

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I'm creating a promise by calling `then`.
Can I somehow report progress from inside it, or do I have to use `Q.defer` (which has `notify`)?

```
var promise = doSomething().then(function () {
   // somehow report progress from here
});

promise.progress(function (p) {
     console.log('progress', p);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out: no, I can't.

See also why [it might not be a good idea after all](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/91).

Answer (score 1):

### Use `deferred.notify()`

It's been a while since this question had been asked, [the `Q` library now support it](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#progress-notification).

```
var progress = 96;
deferred.notify(progress);
```

For example:

```js
function doSomething() {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    
    setTimeout(function() {
        deferred.notify(10);
    },500);

    setTimeout(function() {
        deferred.notify(40);
    },1500);

    setTimeout(function() {
        deferred.notify(60);
    },2500);
    
    setTimeout(function() {
        deferred.notify(100);
        deferred.resolve();
    },3500);

    return deferred.promise;
}

doSomething()
    .then(
        function () {
            // Success
            console.log('done');
        },
        function (err) {
            // There was an error,
        },
        function (progress) {
            // We get notified of the progress as it is executed
            console.log(progress);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/q.js/1.4.1/q.js"></script>
```

---

> #### Progress Notification
>
> It's possible for promises to report their progress, e.g. for tasks
>   that take a long time like a file upload. Not all promises will
>   implement progress notifications, but for those that do, you can
>   consume the progress values using a third parameter to then:
>
> ```
> return uploadFile()
> .then(function () {
>     // Success uploading the file
> }, function (err) {
>     // There was an error, and we get the reason for error
> }, function (progress) {
>     // We get notified of the upload's progress as it is executed
> });
> ```
>
> Like fail, Q also provides a shorthand for progress callbacks called
>   progress:
>
> ```
> return uploadFile().progress(function (progress) {
>     // We get notified of the upload's progress
> });
> ```

- **[taken from the official readme](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#progress-notification)**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "creating a promise by calling `then`". I'm guessing you mean that you're returning a promise with a then defined? I.e,

`var iAmAPromise = someOtherPromise.then(doSomething);`

If this is the case then you can wrap the `doSomething` in a callback function with the appropriate notifications.  A working example:

```
var Q = require('q');

function resolver(deferred){
  return function(){
    deferred.resolve('return value from initial promise');
  }
}

function someOtherPromise( ms ) {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  setTimeout( resolver(deferred) , ms );
  return deferred.promise;
}

function doSomething(data, cb){
  console.log('----- doing something with:', data);
  var val = "Did something with: " + data;
  cb(val);
}

function reportProgress(doSomething, notifierCb){
  notifierCb('waiting on it');
  return function(someOtherPromiseResponse){
    console.log('--- got promise response: ', someOtherPromiseResponse);
    notifierCb('got response',  someOtherPromiseResponse);
    console.log('--- do something with it');
    notifierCb('doing something with it');
    doSomething(someOtherPromiseResponse, function(val){
      notifierCb('done, result was:', val);
    });
  };
}

function notifier(update, detail){
  console.log('Notifier update:', update, detail||"");
}

function logError(err){
  console.log('ERROR:', err);
}

var iAmAPromise = someOtherPromise(1000).then(reportProgress(doSomething, notifier)).catch(logError);

console.log('  (Am I a Promise?)', Q.isPromise(iAmAPromise));
```

I may have misunderstood your question though.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I added a code sample. I understand I can use arbitrary callback, but I wonder if I can somehow make Q's `promise` handler work without using `Q.defer`.